# How to Effect a Return Value from Void Method

Tags: java, interface

Here's my code:

```
deleteStuffFromDb(); // void method
deleteStuffFromCache();
```

deleteStuffFromDb() is an interface method with the return type, `void`.

Ideally, the first method would return a value (Success/Failure). This return value would determine whether the second method executes.

I could modify the interface since it gets called by 2 classes. However, there's still the risk that, as an O&M developer without a full picture of the system, I could break something.

How do you propose that I determine whether this void deleteStuffFromDb()'s execution determines the deleteStuffFromCache()'s execution.

Here are some ways I've thought:

1. put a try/catch around deleteStuffFromDb(), throwing an exception for an error case. If the catch() is encountered, then don't execute the deleteStuffFromCache().
2. put the logic of the deleteStuffFromCache() into the method, deleteStuffFromDb(), and allow/disallow its execution within this method
3. ...?

Please give me your thoughts and reasons for your choice.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the interface public, protected, package private, or private? The more private it is the more freedom you have to change it.

Comment: It is public. But why does the private keyword give me more freedom to change it?

Comment: @Kevin Because the more protected->package private->private, the fewer other classes can even see it.

Comment: @Kevin exactly as EJP says and more specifically if it is private then you only have to verify that changes do not break anything in the source file that contains the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could modify the interface since it gets called by 2 classes.
>   However, there's still the risk that, as an O&M developer without a
>   full picture of the system

If the full picture of the system is that it is only used in two places, you should certainly change them both. A full recompile and system test will reveal whether anything else is broken.

Comment: You're recommending this view since other solutions, like building a wrapper, are inelegant?

Comment: Heck yeah.  If you want to return something, you should make sure you can return it the normal way.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure of the point of your question. I'm recommending it as the solution because it *is* the solution. Everything else is a workaround; workarounds are inelegant, by definition. It hardly needs stating.

Comment: I like that reply. Thanks EJP

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the `deleteStuffFromDb()`'s signature to `deleteStuffFromDb(Object returnObject)`

Then write a wrapper interface to replace the old signature `deleteStuffFromDb()`

In the wrapper interface, do:

```
void deleteStuffFromDb() {
     // initialize some dummy returnObject that doesnt get used
     deleteStuffFromDb(dummyObject);
}
```

To use this system, pass in a `returnObject` to the interface to capture the return value.

This way you can optionally get a return value from the interface if you desire, but without breaking existing calls that use the old interface.

Comment: Ah, so I could, for example, pass in "int returnValue," and then check its value for success/failure before executing deleteStuffFromCache()?

Comment: @Kevin No, you have to pass in a mutable object of some kind, but see my answer. Don't build unnecessary workarounds.

Comment: @Kevin primitive types like int are passed by value (copied), objects are passed by reference (a reference to the object is passed)

Comment: You can't put code in an interface, so how is this going to work? (Also, I'd think that passing in `null` would be a better option than passing in an actual object)

Comment: Apart from the valid pass by value point, I personally don't like int as a way of indicating a result. It relies on the caller knowing what your magic numbers mean. Whilst you can have constants to add 'clarity' e.g. SUCCESS=1, you run the risk that someone thoughtlessly changes the constant code (FAILUIRE=1)and suddenly the whole meaning of your application changes and nothing would complain. A result object would be better (in my opinion) - it also provides the ability to provide data rich results (if needed)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think changing the return type from void to something else will break any existing code.

If the return type is void then any code that is using it is not expecting any return from that method. Also it would break right then if it did.

Now if you change it and return some value from the method then in the case of the existing code, the value returned will just be ignored.

You cannot use a void method where the method is expected to return some value, but you can do the reverse.

The only case I can I think of, that changing it could be a problem is if there are lots of implementations of that interface.

As far as the second point goes, I would prefer to keep the logic where it belongs. May be just call the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how good this sound to you, but I have seen the methods (e.g. `Scanner.html#next()` throws `NoSuchElementException` and `IllegalStateException` based on the failure reason. There are many more such examples), which are meant for success throwing exception in case of failure e.g.

```
 public void deleteStuffFromDb(){
      ..... usual code..
      if (failedCondition){
           throw new RuntimeErrorException(new Error("Couldn't delete"));
      }
 }
```

In caller side, if you get the thrown exception, you can assume, it was a failure otherwise success. This way you can avoid changing the interface.

Comment: Yogendra, thanks for your answer. I find the try/catch method to be unclean. It doesn't seem elegant to me to use exceptions as the litmus test for whether a function was successful or not. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @Kevin: Not sure why you feel this is unclean. If you notice, `most of the java methods` e.g. String class methods, Integer class methods.....list goes on, `have the same behavior` i.e. they throw exception when there is some failure. I quoted one example in the update answer. I feel it is more like a pattern in core java methods.